# Jquery submit() wait for file upload prompt

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this simple code and I'm trying to find a way to inlcude the form submitting directly in it.

```
$('#falsebutton').click(function() {
    $('#fileToUpload').click();
});
```

How do I add `$("form").submit();` so it trigger after the file upload prompt?

P.S: I don't have a submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default action of a `button` inside a `form` is to submit the form.  So if you want to do something else, you need to prevent the default action:

```
$('#falsebutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fileToUpload').click();
});
```

Now, if I understood you right, you want to trigger the form submit immediately after the user chooses a file to upload?  If so, you can listen for a `change` event on your file input and submit the form when it fires:

```
$('#fileToUpload').on('change', function() {
    $('form').submit();
});
```